# Changing jQuery stylesheet which is a php file

Tags: php, jquery, css

I want to use jQuery to add some inline CSS which is generated by a PHP file.  I want to be able to print the contents of the PHP file between the `<style>` tags.

Here's the relevant piece of the JS file:

```
$('#settings button.theme').on('click', function(){
    var whichone = $(this).data('file');
    $('<style type="text/css" media="screen" id="changer"></style>')
        .appendTo('head');
    $('#changer').load('http://example.com/css/style.php?details=' + whichone);
});
```

I don't want to change the style.php file as it generates the original CSS quite happily, but when I do the above, I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error in relation to the PHP file.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: HTTP 500 errors usually denote an error when executing your script. Check your PHP log or webserver log to determine the source of the error in your PHP script.

Comment: Are you trying to load content from same domain?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, same domain.

Comment: Turn on php errors, what happens if you just load the PHP file in the browser? Do you get any errors?

Comment: It just prints out the CSS that I want.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to load the CSS via AJAX, just dynamically set the href attribute:

```
$('#settings button.theme').on('click', function(){
    var whichone = $(this).data('file');
    $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" id="changer" />')
        .appendTo('head').attr('href', 'http://example.com/css/style.php?details=' + whichone);
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  Makes sense but still getting the 500 Internal Server Error